# Get the position instead of the value of the highest one bit in integer

Tags: java

How do I get the position, rather than the value, of the highest one bit in integer? I know I can get the value like this:

```
// Prints 8; in 1101, the highest bit is the one denoting 8
int f = 13;
System.out.println("Highest: " + Integer.highestOneBit(f));
```

However, I'd like to get *position* of the highest one bit - in this case, it would be 4 (since `1000` in binary == `8`, the highest one bit is the fourth one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine it with numberOfTrailingZeros:

```
int pos = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(Integer.highestOneBit(f))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Well, you said you were expecting "4", however this answer gives "3".

Comment: Meh, the offset is not that important.

Comment: 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(f) works better.  If f = 0, then it yields 0 as well, instead of 32 like in the solution.

Comment: @KellenMcClain but isn't it somewhat awkward to have the same result for both f=0 and f=1?

Comment: @xs0 Ah, it actually outputs 0 for f = 0 and 1 for f = 1, 2 for f = 2, etc.  So it's 1+ the index.  Do 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(f) for the actual index, which outputs -1 for f = 0, kinda like how String#indexOf outputs -1 when it doesn't find the character.  Anyway, what I wrote before was what I needed; it was the number of bits to shift if I wanted to "push" a number between 0 and f into the least significant bits of another number x.  (I was given f + 1, ie, the number of numbers.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, we can do this mathematically.

We basically want to get 4 from 8, 3 from 4, 2 from 2, 1 from 1, etc.

That is basically doing a log2 on the number and adding 1 to it. There is no `log2` function in the `java.lang.Math` class, but as you may know:

```
logx(y) = log10(y) / log10(x)
```

so we can just do this!

```
(Math.log10(Integer.highestOneBit(f)) / Math.log10(2)) + 1
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It would need a rounding, as it gives `4.0`, but it works.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to convert your Integer to a String using [Integer.toBinaryString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-), then returning its length.

For instance:

```
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(13);
System.out.println(binaryString.length()); <== gives 4
```

Since there won't be any leading zeros.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer ?

Comment: At least it gives the correct answer. The downvotes are pretty inefficient, too.

Comment: Yes, but why do unnecessary conversions between data types and waster computation time and memory when you achieve the same thing with twiddlin' some bits?

Comment: Well, I don't know your use case, but if you need to convert one data from Integer to String, I really think the JVM won't mind considering the near-nonexistent time AND memory. Once again, only an answer, which at least gives the right result.